# Shower going off

Tags: shower

My shower ( low pressure gravity fed ) turns on, water starts coming out slowly until on full. Then after a minute or so goes off and can take 5-6 mins before it comes back on to be able to take a shower. Any ideas???

Comment: More information is needed as to where are you, type of water supply, well or city water, a better explanation as to the starting pressure and what do you mean by "low pressure gravity fed"?

Comment: Down stairs shower gravity fed hot water from tank on first floor, cold water from tank in loft pressure just less than 1 Bar.Town house plumbed direct to rain style shower. When first instated no problem however over last 3-4 months taking longer and longer to get a constant flow. hope this helps.